# How how to create overlapping divs in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create the following layout in bootstrap. I would guess that in the mobile version they would stack on each other. But I am having problems with the purple box above the white background box.

[image]

Here is what I have so far.
[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23bhm29u/)

```
    <section class="light-gray" style="margin-top:60px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="spacer-40"></div>
      <div class="spacer-40"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 clearfix white">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 pull-right purple color-box">
            <p>Want to know how product name can upgrade your profession?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="spacer-40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row textblock">
              <p>
                Short description about free demo. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet
                risus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="text-right button-container">
            more information <a href="#" class="button button-icon gray"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="spacer-40">
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? `position:absolute;` seems to be solution in this case

Comment: Alternatively, you can just style it to look like the divs are overlapping, when in fact there are 3+ divs positioned without deviating from Bootstrap's grid system.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your jsFiddle I notice you have a lot of rows. I slimmed it down to just two rows and set the column spacing for md and lg viewing, so now if viewed on tablet device and larger the devices will be aligned next to each other.

However, in mobile view the purple div goes below the text to maintain a responsive layout.

here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/wcwjgt31/3/) with example updated code.

Hope that helps

UPDATED HTML

```
<section class="light-gray">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">        
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="textblock">
          <p>
            Short description about free demo. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet
            risus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor.
          </p>
           <p>
            Short description about free demo. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet
            risus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor.
          </p>
      </div><!--/.textblock-->
    </div><!--/.cols-->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 purple color-box">
   <p>Want to know how product name can upgrade your profession?</p>
  </div><!--/.cols-->
</div><!--/.row-->
<div class="row">
 <div class="text-right button-container">
   more information <a href="#" class="button button-icon gray"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a>
 </div><!--/.text-right-->
</div><!--/.row-->
</div><!--/.container-->
</section>
```

UPDATED CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans');
.light-gray {
  background: #CCC; /*could not see the grey that was provided */
 }

.white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
 }

.gray {
  background: #474747;
 }

 .purple {
   background: #940c72;
  }

.spacer-40 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
 }

 .color-box {
   padding: 60px;
   right: 0;
   font-family: Times, serif;
   font-size: 1.85em;
   font-style: italic;
   color: white;
}

.textblock {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
 color: #007ac3;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.1s ease-out;
 transition: color 0.1s ease-out;
}

.button-container {
  padding-top: 15px;
 }

 .button-container {
   padding-right: 0px;
 }

.button {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-out;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #007ac3;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.87891rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1.0625rem 0.9375rem;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  width: 100%;
 }

 [class^="icon-"]:before,
 [class*=" icon-"]:before {
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   font-smoothing: grayscale;
   font-style: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-left: .2em;
  margin-right: .2em;
  speak: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  width: 1em;
 }

 .icon-arrow-right:before {
    content: '\e80b';
 }

 .button .button-icon {
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 1.25rem;
   padding: 0.75rem 0.5rem;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.button-container a.button {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   width: auto;
 }
```